# How to use RealmBaseAdapter without memory exceptions?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, realm, realm-base-adapter

I am trying to figure out what is the right way to use the RealmBaseAdapter.

**Background**:

- I have an app with a single activity and many fragments.
- The main screen is a fragment that contains a ViewPager with child fragments (with tabs in the action bar).
- Each child fragment contains a list view that displays realm results using a subclass of RealmBaseAdapter.
- When the user taps on an item in one of the list views an inner fragment is displayed (it replaces the main fragment with all its child fragments).
- For the RealmBaseAdapter to work the Realm object that created the RealmResults has to be open (after getInstance and before close), so I have a base fragment that creates an instance of Realm in onStart and closes it in onDestroy.

**Now the problem**:
There a re too many memory related crashes in the app and I think that I understand the reason.
The problem is that there is always at least one open Realm, which avoids from it to be cleaned.
Meaning that realm grows in the memory all the time and never gets the chance to be cleaned.

According to few memory related issues in the realm's github repo I understand that the realm should be opened and closed for as short operation as possible, but it comes in contrast with the fact that the RealmBaseAdapter requires the originating realm object to be open for all its life time.

Any help/thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the FAQ at https://realm.io/docs/java/0.80.0/#faq explains why the file size of a Realm might increase (see section "Large Realm file size").

I would recommend that you compact your Realm file when the app either starts or resumes (and before it opens a Realm instance). The method `Realm.compactRealmFile()` is the method you should be looking for (see https://realm.io/docs/java/0.80.0/api/io/realm/Realm.html#compactRealmFile-android.content.Context-).

Comment: thank you for your answer. The problem is not in low disk space but in out of memory exception. The app succeeds in opening the realm, fetching the data and displaying it in the list views (more than one). After using the app for some time (sometimes a couple of seconds and sometimes much more) the app crashes while trying to call getInstance method of Realm class.

Comment: I want to emphasize that I have a conceptual problem here. On one hand the realm objects should be closed in order to clear caches (the in-memory cache gets cleared ONLY when there is zero opened realm objects - meaning that close method calls amount is equal to the getInstance method calls amount. But on the other hand the RealmBaseAdapter requires the realm object (which has created the RealmResults) to remain open all the time that the results are displayed. In my case 90% of screens display RealmResults. Which leads to at least one open realm object 100% of the app life time.

Comment: I believe that this is exactly what leads to the out-of-memory exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Christian from Realm here. Without more details about your code, it can be hard to guess at the exact reason, but below is a few hints about how Realm works which might help you.

- You can open as many instances of a Realm on the UI thread as you want. Realm uses a ThreadLocal cache to cache Realms. So opening Realms in onCreate and close them in onDestroy is a perfectly viable pattern.
- All RealmBaseAdapters use the same cached version of the Realm.
- Realm will use extra memory if you have the same Realm open across multiple threads, as it then has to handle that these Realms might be different versions. Forgetting to close Realms in background threads are the most common reason for OOM errors. Especially if you spawn your own threads instead of using Threadpools.
- Using multiple Realm files will increase memory usage, as they are completely separate databases.
- Iterating large RealmResults in tight loops (eg. during animation redraws) can cause OOM errors. This is because Realm currently use finalizers to clean up native memory and finalizers are so slow that the GC thread might not be able to keep up. We have a fix for this here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/922, but it hasn't merged it yet as it also has a negative impact on overall performance. Note that rendering a ListAdapter is not a large dataset as it only renders visible items, but if you fastscroll over thousands of objects for a longer period of time, you might experience OOM.

I hope the above helps, but if you still see these issues, I would encourage you to create an GitHub issue at https://github.com/realm/realm-java so we can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I have pretty the same issue as this one: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/794 .

Comment: We use a worker thread almost as the one in the sample project(s). ALL the writes are performed on this worker thread and there are no long transactions. We have tried to can getInstance on the worker thread creation and call close on its termination (as in your example), tried to call getInstance and close for each separate operation on this thread.

Comment: In addition we have the realm adapters on most of the fragments. We have noticed that if we close the realm that created the RealmResults for the adapter right after fetching the data then we receive an appropriate exception saying something like "you are trying to use a realm object but its realm is closed".

Comment: And finally, we have few places where the realm is used to fetch a short portion of data and close. All the getInstance calls are balanced with close.

Comment: In that GitHub issue emanuelez says: "If you call getInstance N times and then close N times, then the only Nth
time you call close will actually perform the cleanup of the native
resources and delete the cached Realm instance." From this I understand that calling 'getInstance' in 'onCreate' and calling 'close' in 'onTerminate' is bad pattern to follow. Meaning that the cache will never be cleared until the app will "explode" the memory...